# How do you prevent a NodeJS server from potentially exposing function code?

Tags: javascript

Let's imagine you're building a banking app backend. You want to respond to a user with a string that returns the balance but you forgot to add `()`.

```
class User {
  constructor() {console.log("ctor")}
  balance() { console.log("secret balance code")}
}
```

Then when referencing the user, instead of writing this:

```
const userA = new User();
return `Your balance is $${userA.balance()}`;
```

I accidentally write this:

```
const userA = new User();
return `Your balance is $${userA.balance}`;
```

Which sadly outputs:

```
'Your balance is balance() { console.log("secret balance code")}'
```

Which leaks the source code.

Comment: Write test coverage - you can ensure the responses are what you expect them to be.

Comment: ...or use TypeScript :) It covers most of these situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to override all functions' `toString` like so:

```
> Function.prototype.toString = () => {return "bla"}
[Function]
> '' + new User().balance
'bla'
```

Comment: It's a pretty awful idea to override prototypes that aren't yours.  Overriding `Function` will most definitely break some debugging and logging tools.

Comment: Here's another way about it but you have to protect every single function separately so wouldn't be accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799996/node-js-prevent-function-inspection-tostring I think a typescript lint warning would be the best option to solve this question.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to worry about it, if you forget something, then testing will help to find it. Nobody deploy in production without testing when he has a serious project. It is better to write tests than to try to correct language behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When responding to a request, you're undoubtedly going to be running the response through some sort of serializer.  JSON, CBOR, etc.  Handle it on that layer.

Fortunately for you, if you're returning JSON data, it's already handled:

```
JSON.stringify(someFunction);
// undefined
```

If you really are returning plain text strings, you can still have such a layer that ensures you're not putting out functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've a solution which is definitely slower than raw templates, but here it goes.

So basically I just send a context object which has all the string I want to resolve. And before the actual string replacement, I just check for the types of arguments.

```
function resolveTemplates(str, args){
  if(args && Array.isArray(args) && args.length){
    args.forEach((argument) => {
      // check here for any unwanted types
      if(typeof arg === 'function'){
        throw new Error('Cannot send function to create raw Strings')
      }
    })
  }

  const rx = /\{([^{}]*)\}/g;

  let match = {};
  let matches = [];
  while(match = rx.exec(str)){
    matches.push(match)    
  }

  matches.reverse();
  matches.forEach(function(match){
    const key = match[1];
    const index = match.index;
    str = str.slice(0, index) + args[key] + str.slice(index + 2 + key.length) 
  })

  return str;
}


resolveTemplates('Hello! My name is {firstName} {lastName}', {firstName: 'Shobhit', lastName: 'Chittora'})
```

PS: Instead of throwing errors for functions as arguments, you can call the functions. But binding the functions to the correct context can be a overhead to think about and generally not suggested.

Comment: Repl link to test this out -> https://repl.it/talk/share/HomelyAlertShelfware/13727